# Error trying to group in Magento join

Tags: magento, join, grid, grouping

I'm facing the error in title with Magento. I'm trying to group the records in the grid by county, which is one of the fields obtained in the join, not the main table. When I run the SQL query generated against DB it runs as expected but when trying to access the grid in Magento, I get that error. This is my join:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('region')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('city')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('address_type', 'shipping')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('region', 'California')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
            ->addFieldToFilter(array('status', 'status'),
                array(
                    array('eq' => 'complete'),
                    array('eq' => 'processing')
                ));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('order' => 'sales_flat_order'),
            'order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id',
            array('status' => 'order.status',
                'created_at' => 'order.created_at',
                'grand_total' => 'SUM(order.grand_total)'))
            ->joinLeft(
                array('order_tax' => 'sales_order_tax'),
                'order_tax.order_id = main_table.parent_id',
                array('county' => 'order_tax.title',
                    'tax_amount' => 'SUM(order_tax.amount)',
                    'tax_rate' => 'order_tax.percent'))
            ->group('county')
            ->group('city')
            ->distinct(true);
```

And this is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`region`, `main_table`.`city`, `order`.`status`, `order`.`created_at`, SUM(order.grand_total) AS `grand_total`, `order_tax`.`title` AS `county`, SUM(order_tax.amount) AS `tax_amount`, `order_tax`.`percent` AS `tax_rate` FROM `sales_flat_order_address` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `mvmt_sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id LEFT JOIN `mvmt_sales_order_tax` AS `order_tax` ON order_tax.order_id = main_table.parent_id WHERE (address_type = 'shipping') AND (region = 'California') AND (created_at >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2013-12-31 00:00:00') AND ((status = 'complete') OR (status = 'processing')) GROUP BY `county`, `city`
```

Does someone knows what is happening here and why SQL is accepting the query but not Magento?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('region')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('country_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('city')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('address_type', 'shipping')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('region', 'California')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
          ->addFieldToFilter(array('status', 'status'),
                array(
                    array('eq' => 'Pending'),
                    array('eq' => 'processing')
                ));
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('order' => 'sales_flat_order'),
            'order.entity_id = main_table.parent_id',
            array('order.status','order.created_at','SUM(order.grand_total)'));
                $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('order_tax' => 'sales_order_tax'),
                'order_tax.order_id = main_table.parent_id',
                array('order_tax.title','SUM(order_tax.amount)','order_tax.percent'))

      ->group('country_id')
            ->group('city')
             ->distinct(true);
```

Hope this will work for you. :)
Best of luck.

Comment: Spreading your contact info all over the place might be considered ... *spam* - please remove it from all your answers

Comment: I appreciate your time, but it is not about CONTRY, but COUNTY, which is the alias I assign to the field: `order_tax.title`.